# How to measure text size in rendered html?

Tags: html, google-chrome, rendering

I am trying to build a tool to understand which words are bigger than others on a large set of html pages (without javascript). I am looking for a way to compute the size of the text displayed on the page from a Python program.

I checked solutions like BeautifulSoup (Python) to check in-line styles, but it does not work with CSS classes.

Any ideas of a more comprehensive solution?